# Minecraft Command Blocks: Teleport Player Even If On Horse?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When spawning on our server, the player is located on an island we've dubbed "Spawn Island" (Original name isn't it?). On this island is a series of platforms with pressure plates. Under the pressure plates are command blocks encapsulated in bedrock. The command blocks have a tp command to teleport anyone standing on the platform to their respective destinations. At the destination is a duplicate platform with the ccounterpart command block to teleport them back to the proper platform.

The system works well with one big problem we've found. If a player is riding a horse, the horse does not teleport and is left wandering around near the departing platform.

Is there a way to change the command to teleport a player as well as any horse they are riding (preferably staying on the horse if so)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/168210):

`/execute @a ~ ~ ~ tp @e[type=EntityHorse,r=1] <x> <y> <z>`

This command will, at every player location, teleport the player and any horse within a 1 block radius to the location specified by `<x> <y> <z>`. The player will not be riding the horse, unfortunately, and I don't believe there's any way to keep players on a horse.